# Uint8Array saved in text mode instead of binary

Tags: javascript, blob

I have Uint8Array with values `97`,`98`,`99` and `100`. When I do

```
var blob = new Blob(new Uint8Array([97,98,99,100]), {type: "application/octet-stream" });
const a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
a.setAttribute("download", "binaryData.random");
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

It's starts downloading file but when I open it, it contains `979899100` instead of `abcd`. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Blob` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob) takes an array of byte-sequence objects, not a single one. It currently interprets each element of your `Uint8Array` as a string.

```
const bytes = new Uint8Array([97,98,99,100]);
const blob = new Blob([bytes], {type: "application/octet-stream" });
//                    ^     ^
```

Comment: Thank you, did not see that ‍♂️